# Sync column in two different spreadsheets from imported data

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a private spreadsheet and a shared spreadsheet with data imported from the private one. I want users to be able to make changes to the shared spreadsheet, that will reflect on the private one. For example, I would like users to be able to uncheck column A cell 1 here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JX6XFGJksanTPIrN7oqVf1iDDIxXeFDG8Xq3iHXGEBo/edit?usp=sharing and have the change reflect on the private spreadsheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16FJzFqWkyN9vy2E3IFpaifybwfdoq-iLj_qKZsnQau8/edit#gid=0

```
=IMPORTRANGE("16FJzFqWkyN9vy2E3IFpaifybwfdoq-iLj_qKZsnQau8", "Sheet1!A1:U1000")
```

I expect to be able to change data in shared spreadsheet and have it reflect on the private spreadsheet

Comment: Currently, i am not able check or uncheck the checkbox on the shared spreadsheet. It says that doing so will overwrite data in 'A2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMPORTRANGE` and all other formulae are 1-directional which means that your issue can be solved only this way:

the private spreadsheet consists of green cells with the red formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID_of_shared_spreadsheet", "shared!B1:C")
```

[image: 0]

and shared spreadsheet consists of green cells and this red formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID_of_private_spreadsheet", "private!A1:A")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The private sheet will need to check that the `Issue Addressed` column is checked and send an email based on that condition. Would suggest configuring this differently? Perhaps I could create an `Issue Addressed` column in the shared spreadsheets, and import to the private sheet instead?

Copies of the spreadsheets I am working with: 
Private sheet - <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_0WThnQa6G1A6ZvCegwa_eFRE4D4qUXgmA9TvqT4cCM/edit?usp=sharing>

Shared Sheet -<https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M1AClhbjfzkjFyHXfJHRzCtkatvPqJyNtrumV0ufaPg/edit?usp=sharing>

Comment: well, checkboxes need to be checkable in a shared sheet while values in shared sheet should be "borrowed" from private sheet

Comment: I think I understand. I am just not sure how checking the box on the shared sheet would change the value on the private sheet. Could I have `A1` on the private sheet check the Shared sheet and change the value in `A1` if column B on the Shared Sheet is `TRUE`. 

I tried to replicate your example here: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JX6XFGJksanTPIrN7oqVf1iDDIxXeFDG8Xq3iHXGEBo/edit?usp=sharing 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16FJzFqWkyN9vy2E3IFpaifybwfdoq-iLj_qKZsnQau8/edit#gid=0

Comment: @THRILLHOUSE [shared sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYKJHoZtYNM-Cs_e-phmeHs7GFZy6vheFmseX7HwaKY/edit#gid=0) and [private sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJLBpNJFhbhPuOY1W4mwAnSq4qQFZ1ARHydKs-Q5Iw8/edit#gid=0) eg. replication of the answer

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question. I just didn't ask the right question. I need to make the value in `A1` on the private sheet change to `TRUE` when a checkbox on the shared sheet in the same row is checked.